# How to compile C code (or a 32-bit dll file) into 64-bit dll file?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, compilation, 64-bit

I want to compile my C code into 64-bit dll file. I used this command in cmd:

```
gcc main.c --shared -o main.dll
```

and it compiles my code into a 32-bit dll file. How should I compile it into 64-bit one? (or even is it possible to convert the 32-bit dll file into the 64-bit one?)
Note that I'm using windows 10 x64.

Comment: It is not possible to convert a 32-bit DLL to a 64-bit one. You need a 64-bit build of gcc.

Comment: Did you try passing ***-m64*** to *gcc*? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS C compiler, it does not have 64bit compiler.
GCC has both 32bit and 64bit compiler. So you can use 64bit compiler to run your program 64bit.
By the way, you can give a try to Clang compiler. It has also 64bit operations.
To install GCC and Clang your can use [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/).